# How to validate greyed out tab on windows app via selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest, winappdriver

I'm working on MSTest framework where the window based app is automated using selenium with .net C#.

**I have a scenario to automate where all the options (tab, text or button etc) present on windows app are greyed out. So, when a user try to click on any of those option nothing should happen**.

I thought to take the locator of any these option and put a bool condition to see if an app refresh or not, when user try to click on greyed out option. But I am not able to think well how to do so as I'm not good in coding :(

I took the AccessibilityId (locator) of the option (eg: Tab) and observe that in debug mode that WindowsApplicationDrive is returning Element in id form to the variable. So, now I don't know how to use the bool condition to validate this.
Any example help would be appreciated which I can relate and try to test the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the buttons etc attributes - for instance if button is set to Disabled. Inspect the button when 'greyed out' and see what is set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).